# VIM: How to map c-] (tags) to do g + lookup tag?

Tags: vim, remap

The usual, default mapping for `Ctrl-]` seems to be `"lookup tag under cursor"`.  If I want the list of all possible tag hits, I have to press `"g"` then `ctrl-]`.

How do I `noremap <silent> <C-]>` to be `g + "lookup tag under cursor"`?  I expect the results in a window(?) at the bottom of the screen just like usual.

And, of course, I want this because I forget the "g" all-too-often.

Comment: Not that I'd ever have recognized the subject as being the same, but, yes, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the most obvious solution is just what you need:

```
nmap <C-]> g<C-]>
```